# Rcpp: retrieve and replace off-diagonal values of a square matrix

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

Using Rcpp/Armadillo, how can I efficiently extract/replace off-diagonal values of a square matrix? In R it can be achieved using: `old_values = A[row(A) == (col(A) - k)]`; `A[row(A) == (col(A) - k)] = new_values`. Using Armadillo a for-loop (see below) can be used to achive this goal. But is there a  simpler way to write the code? As I need to do this operation for all `k` of a big matrix (>10000 rows, > 10000 columns), efficiency is better to be considered. Here is a reproducible example:

```
A = matrix(1:25, 5, 5) 

A[row(A) == (col(A) - 3)] # extract the 3rd off-diagnal values
A[row(A) == (col(A) - 2)] = -5 of # replace the 2nd off-diagnal values with -5
```

The cpp code using a for loop:

```
arma::vec retrieve_off_diag_values( arma::mat A, unsigned k )
    {
        unsigned n_cols = A.n_cols;
        arma::vec off_diag_values(n_cols - k);
        for( unsigned i=0; i <(n_cols - k); i++ )
        {
            off_diag_values(i) = A(i, i+k);
        } 
        return off_diag_values;
    }
```

Comment: Since you are dealing with a big matrix, you should avoid copying the matrix. Your function is currently defined to do an implicit copy of the input matrix: `retrieve_off_diag_values(arma::mat A)`.  To avoid the copy, change it to `retrieve_off_diag_values(const arma::mat& A)`.  The `&` character is critically important.

Answer (score 1):

#### Retrieving off-diagonal

You can use armadillo's [`.diag()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#diag) member function with an index `k` to retrieve off-diagonal.

Cases:

- if `k == 0` (default), then the main diagonal.
- else if `k < 0`, then a lower triangular diagonal.
- else then an upper triangular diagonal.

Example:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec offdiag_extract(arma::mat& A, int k) {
  return A.diag(k);
}
```

Test:

```
A = matrix(1:25, 5, 5) 
offdiag_extract(A, 3)
#      [,1]
# [1,]   16
# [2,]   22
```

#### Replacing off-diagonal

**Edit:** This section has been updated thanks to @mtall's point regarding behavior provided by other member functions.

However, [`.diag()=`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#diag) can only be used to save into the main diagonal. To ensure the replacement being viable for all diagonals, you would need to chain the [`.diag()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#diag) member function with [`.fill(value)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fill), e.g.

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat offdiag_fill_arma(arma::mat& A, int k, double replace_value) {
    A.diag(k).fill(replace_value);
    return A;
}
```

Test:

```
offdiag_fill_arma(A, 2, 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    6    4   16   21
# [2,]    2    7   12    4   22
# [3,]    3    8   13   18    4
# [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
# [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

#### Implementing off-diagonal replacement

In short, one could implement off-diagonal replacement using a single `for` loop with the appropriate `k` offset.

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat offdiag_replace(arma::mat& A, int k, double replace_val = -5) {

  // Determine whether to go over upper or lower diagonal  
  unsigned int row_offset = (k < 0) ? -k : 0;
  unsigned int col_offset = (k > 0) ?  k : 0;

  // Compute total number of elements
  unsigned int N = std::min(A.n_rows - row_offset, A.n_cols - col_offset);

  // Loop over diagonal
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

    unsigned int row = i + row_offset;
    unsigned int col = i + col_offset;

    // Disregard bounds checks with .at()
    A.at(row,col) = replace_val;
  }

  return A;
}
```

Test:

```
offdiag_replace(A, 2, 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    6    4   16   21
# [2,]    2    7   12    4   22
# [3,]    3    8   13   18    4
# [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
# [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Comment: For the replacement, it's possible to use simpler and shorter code: `A.diag(k).fill(replace_val)`.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about that. Thanks @mtall. I've added in that as a point.

Answer (score 1):

To extract values from a specified diagonal into a vector, where k < 0 indicates subdiagonals, k = 0 indicates the main diagonal, and k > 0 indicates superdiagonals:

```
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec diag_get(const arma::mat& X, int k)   // note the 'const' and '&'
{
    return X.diag(k);
}
```

To set values on a diagonal to a specific value:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void diag_fill(arma::mat& X, int k, double value)   // note the '&' character
{
    X.diag(k).fill(value);
}
```

To change instances of a specific value on a diagonal with another value:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void diag_change(arma::mat& X, int k, double old_value, double new_value)
{
    X.diag(k).replace(old_value, new_value);
}
```